# Save image to phone loaded from gallery

Tags: android, storage, image-uploading

I'm trying to save an image loaded from the gallery to the phone memory(local path). Can anyone guide me into this?

This is how I get the image from the gallery.

```
ImageView profilePicture;
private Uri imageUri;
String picturePath;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
{
     profilePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
        profilePicture.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                switch (arg1.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
                    uploadImage();
                    break;
                }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
}
```

uploadImage()

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,     android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);  
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                Bitmap bitmap;
                try {
                     bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                     .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                     profilePicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
                }
            }
        case 1:
             if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                 String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                         filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                 cursor.moveToFirst();

                 int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                 picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                 cursor.close();
                 profilePicture.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                     profilePicture.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

             }

        }
    }
```

*Note: Case 0  is for image capturing using phones camera.

I can display it on my imageview but I need to store this in the phone's memory so everytime I will open the app, I will be able to load the previous uploaded image to the image view. Then if the user wants to upload again. The file previously saved will just be overwritten. I don't want to result to storing images as blob using sqlite since I will be uploading just one image for my whole app. I want to store it in a local file path like myappname/images/image.png. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store an image in the application cache directory such as:

```
try {
    String destFolder = getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/images/";
        if (!new File(destFolder).exists()) {
            new File(destFolder).mkdirs();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFolder + "profile.png");    
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();               
}
```

And read back the file into the Bitamp:

```
String fname = "profile.png";
Bitmap profile = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/images/"  + fname);
```

Comment: I will try this. But can you please point out which part in the image saving is the line where I'm referencing the image that I currently have? As you can see. The image that I got from the gallery is directly stored in the imageview. This line. profilePicture.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath)); Is the bitmap.compress the image that I have? So I should just store BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath) to a bitmap for ex. bm. Then use this in the compress ex: bm.compress?

Comment: This is your Bitmap: BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath)); so try to set: BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath)).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

Comment: I stored it to a bitmap variable to make it more organized. +1 Nice and simple answer. Just what I need. No other unnecessary codes and work-arounds. Straight to the point. Thanks!

Comment: Follow up question. If I try to upload another image. Will this overwrite the existing file that was currently saved in the application cache directory?